# Regex to match all alphanumeric and certain special characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a regex to work that will allow all alphanumeric characters (both caps and non caps as well as numbers) but also allow spaces, forward slash (`/`), dash (`-`) and plus (`+`)?

I've got a start but so far no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to allow *only* those, you will also need the use of the anchors `^` and `$`.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s\+\-\/]+$
^                    ^^
```

This is your regex and I added characters as indicated from the second line. Don't forget the `+` or `*` near the end to allow for more than 1 character (0 or more in the case of `*`), otherwise the regex will try to match only one character, even with `.Matches`.

You can also replace the whole class `[A-Za-z0-9_]` by one `\w`, like so:

```
^[\w\s\+\-\/]+$
```

EDIT:

You can actually avoid some escaping and avoid one last escaping with a careful placement (i.e. ensure the `-` is either at the beginning or at the end):

```
^[\w\s+/-]+$
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I managed to get it to work using your example, much appreciated! I was getting the multitude of single characters, your explanation not only resolved my issue but also helped me to learn why it wasn't working in the first place :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your regex would look something like:

```
/[\w\d\/\-\+ ]+/g
```

That's all letters, digits, and / - + and spaces (but not any other whitespace characters)

The + at the end means that at least 1 character is required. Change it to a * if you want to allow an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This code does that:

```
var input = "Test if / this+-works&sec0nd 2 part*3rd    part";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"([0-9a-zA-Z /+-]+)");

foreach (Match m in matches) if (m.Success) Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

And output will have 3 result lines:

- Test if / this+-works
- sec0nd 2 part
- 3rd---part (I showed spaces with - here)