# C# replace all other characters in the string other then whitelisted characters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a list of allowed characters in my application.
1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .,'()?!#$%^*;:+=-_

What i want's if my string contain any characters other then above it will be replace with string.empty
How can i do it

Comment: btw: "it will be replaced with string.Empty": do you mean _the whole string_ should be emptied or only the illegal characters should be removed?

Comment: Only illegal characters. I can do it myself but a questions was from colleague. So posted it here which can result in a quick solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833939/regex-to-match-all-alphanumeric-and-certain-special-characters

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj That is a better duplicate indeed.

Comment: Better duplicate :)

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. The referenced question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885964/regex-to-replace-invalid-characters wants to replace invalid characters from a string (blacklist principle) while this question wants to preserve certain characters in a string and remove all the rest (whitelist principle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a *list* of allowed characters, I suggest testing against this *list*; something like that (*Linq*):

```
  // HashSet is efficient to find items O(1)
  private static HashSet<char> s_Allowed = new HashSet<char>(
    @"1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,'()?!#$%^*;:+=");

  ...
  string source = "123~~~456";

  // "123456"
  string result = string.Concat(source
    .Where(c => s_Allowed.Contains(c)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmirty

Comment: For those interested in performance: The Regex approach of Rumpelstinsk is quicker for large strings compared to the Linq approach Dmitry Bychenko. This is probably due to the fact that Linq is generally slower in iterating trough the given source string but Regex generates some overhead at initialization time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex replacement. Try this:

```
public static string formatToken(string token)
    {
        //To prevent null exception
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token)) return token;

        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 .,'()?!#$%*;:+=-_]"); //Maybe some characters need to be scaped. 
        return rgx.Replace(token, "");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rumpelstick